# How does Terminal read from stdout and draw the text on-screen?

Tags: c, linux, macos, bash, unix

I have a general question about how the terminal and processes work.

From any process, if I write to stdout (i.e. file descriptor 2), it gets drawn on the terminal window. My question is, how is this actually implemented? Is stdout an actual 'dummy' file somewhere that the terminal keeps on reading from and drawing the content on screen? Or is there some kind of IPC between the process/stdout stream and the Terminal?

Note that when I say terminal, I mean some general GUI terminal/console, such as Terminal on the Mac.

P.S. If this question is unclear, let me know and I will happily try to explain again :)

Thanks!

Comment: The genius(?) of Unix is that everything is a file, Devices and all.

Comment: Stdout is file descriptor 1. Stdin is zero, stderr is 2

Answer (score 6):

The magic part here that you don't seem to be aware of is the kernel's tty layer.

Each terminal window you open corresponds to a [pseudoterminal device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) — for instance, `/dev/ttys001` is a name for one such device on Mac OS X. By default, any process that's running in a terminal and which doesn't have its input/output redirected from/to somewhere else, its standard input, output, and error are all set to one of these devices. For instance, if I run `lsof` on a `cat` process running in a terminal, I see:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
...
cat     52919 user    0u   CHR   16,5    0t4562     3313 /dev/ttys005
cat     52919 user    1u   CHR   16,5    0t4562     3313 /dev/ttys005
cat     52919 user    2u   CHR   16,5    0t4562     3313 /dev/ttys005
```

When a process writes to a pseudoterminal slave device, the output is routed to the process holding the master end of the connection (in this case, your terminal application), which can read it. Similarly, when a terminal application writes to a pseudoterminal master device, the data becomes available to any process that's reading from the corresponding slave device.

There are a few other tricks involved with pseudoterminal devices. Most notably, they have an inherent size in rows and columns, which an application running in them can query, they can perform certain simple translations on data passing through them (for instance, CR to CR/LF, backspace to DEL, and other such things), and they can generate signals when certain characters are seen (e.g, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> generates an interrupt signal to the foreground process). There's a lot of weird historical subtleties here, but the point is that the kernel's tty layer is where most of this behavior exists.

Pseudoterminal devices are created using the [`forkpty()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty) libc function. The details of how this works behind the scenes vary from platform to platform, and can get pretty hairy, so I won't dig into the details.

Answer (score 5):

When you include stdio.h, stdout is a variable defined there.

To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output)

> stdout - a pointer to a FILE which refers to the standard output stream, usually a display terminal

And, as Russ C mentioned, everything is a file in Unix, so you are right in that respect.

And [apparently](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_stdout.htm), every unix program that is opened has its output, input, and error streams set, by default, to stdout, stdin, and stderr, respectively. They can be changed, though. Like in terminal where you [redirect](http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html) the standard input of a file by using '<', which you probably do in statements like

```
mysql -u root -p dbname < ./data.sql
```

I guess this doesn't really answer all of your question about the real details of the implementation, but knowing that it's a file stream can probably give you a pretty good idea of what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the big picture.

1. The terminal is a device. It's a piece of hardware, and you can make things appear on it by writing data to its hardware interface.
2. Operating systems delegate the handling of this (and any hardware device) to a device driver. The device driver essentially offers a software interface to the device. You can then make things appear on the terminal by invoking this device driver software interface.
3. In *nix systems, the device drivers expose the hardware devices they control as files in the file system. You can open these files, and invoke the software interface offered by the device driver (via open, ioctl, close etc.).
4. The C library has a layered I/O system that underneath opens these files and invokes the device driver interface on your behalf. You can do it yourself too, but just know that any library functions you use are doing this too.
5. By default, when a process is created, descriptors 1 and 2 are opened onto the terminal device. So when you write to these descriptors, the underlying driver receives the data, and talks to the hardware device to render the characters on the screen.
6. When you pipe the output of a process to another process or redirect the output to a file, the descriptors are reopened on to other devices like a pipe, or a file, and the data you write to them ends up in the corresponding device driver, and eventually the hardware device.

Comment: "the descriptors 0 and 1 are opened on to the terminal device." Did you mean descriptors 1 and 2? I thought file descriptor 0 isn't opened on a terminal device but the keyboard.

Comment: @uzluisf you are correct. I wasn't thinking. Fixed in the answer.